# TYPO3 - file upload, overwrite by default

Tags: file-upload, typo3

is there a way to upload a file/picture/whatever in typo3 and not have it renamed/suffixed with a number?
to put it another way, is there a way to overwrite files by default when uploading in typo?
thanks in advance

Comment: For what reason would you like to overwrite files? Because of disk space or something else? (and why is this question down voted :-/ )

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that via TSconfig.

You would have to alter the TYPO3 source (take a look at `typo3/sysext/filelist/mod1/file_list.php`), but this will obviously break when you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try the DAM extension. It creates symlinks instead of copies of files when refering to them multiple times.